# Jquery return value from $.post() in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I've got a Javascript function called `getCartProducts()` which gets a JSON array via AJAX using `$.post()` which returns a value. I want to let my function return that value, but I don't know how to do that.

Here's my function:

```
function getCartProduct(id){
  $.post('core/ajax/getCartProduct.ajax.php', {id: parseInt(id)}, function(data){
    var result = data;
  });
  return result;
}
```

I know that this wont work, because te variable result is only active in the `$.post()` function, but I don't know how to get it straight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a callback function (AJAX is Asynchronous, so your return is being hit before there is any data to return):

```
function returnData(param) {
    console.log(param);
}
```

Now add that callback function as a parameter to your AJAX function, and lets run it:

```
function getCartProduct(id, callback){
    $.post('core/ajax/getCartProduct.ajax.php', {id: parseInt(id)}, function(data){
        callback(data);
    });
}

getCartProduct(id, returnData);
```

Comment: please read the duplicate question, and then use the "deferred" object method from its accepted answer.  It's far more powerful than passing callbacks around.  The "modern" way is to `return $.post(...)` and then the caller can process the resulting promise with `getCartProduct(myId).done(function(data) { ... })`

Comment: If you do decide to use a callback, consider using the line... `if (typeof callback != "undefined") { callback(data); }` This way you have the option to send a callback or not.