# Jquery ajax not returning data while console does

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code inside a JS function:

```
$.post('script/route.php', {deliveryAddress: address}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    return "The distance to your location is "+data+ ".";
});
```

This function posts to a PHP file that calculates the distance between two addresses. The console shows the correct distance, but the string with data is not returned for some reason, the complete return seems to be ignored. How can this happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394362/jquery-return-value-from-post-in-function

Comment: Return to where ?

Comment: You're returning a string to nowhere, do you want to show it somewhere?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz the return is being added to a div. Apparantly it has something to do with asynchronous calls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/4248328

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987811/why-cant-i-return-data-from-post-jquery

Comment: If you are using jquery version < 1.8 use $.ajax() with option async:false

Comment: Using async: false on an AJAX request defeats the purpose of AJAX at the first place